# cypress cucumber processor setup

Tags: testing, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Hello and thanks for the help. i recently setup cypress and although the .feature file runs, when ever i create a new .feature file (and call an existing step), i get the error [Step implementation missing for: Newly created Admin User logs in].

im not sure why this is the case but iv followed the setup in the docs. Some more details below

```
package.json
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^10.0.3",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.0",
    "cypress-visual-regression": "^1.7.0",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^1.18.3"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration",
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  }
```

**plugins/index.js**

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

**my cypress.config.json**

```
 e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration',
    supportFile: './cypress/support/index.js',
  },
```

**my folder structure is attached**

[image: folder structure]

**error after run**
as you can see i am running the file new.feature which i copied from from a previous tests which already have steps created. the other tests [login.feature and account.feature] seem to work but as soon as i create a new /feature file, that new file doesnt run. not sure why cypress doesnt fine the existing steps. please help. thanks
[image]

Comment: Where is the step implementation written for the new feature file?

Answer (score 0):

Funny but true When I copy the Scenario from 1 feature file/OneNote  to another feature file this happens, since the keywords Given, when, Then is not recognized

Delete the keywords, type it manually and select it from the auto suggestions and viola the  feature file should execute.

Comment: can you share a screen shot pls?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my specPattern like below, and it worked:

```
specPattern: "**/*.feature"
```